# vhdl signed and unsigned type endianess

Tags: vhdl, endianness, signed

I am writing a code in vhdl quite full of algebraic operations and I declared some signed variables (I know that there are better types, but I needed to reduce the bits used). I was wondering if it is better to declare them as

```
variable foo1 := signed (7 downto 0);
```

or

```
variable foo2 := signed (0 to 7);
```

I know it is related to endianess, but I am fairly confused. For example, if I declare

```
variable foo3 := signed (0 to 7) := "01100100";
```

Will it be interpreted as 100 or 38 in decimal? And if I have a condition on `foo3` as

```
if (foo3(1) = '1') then
-- whatever you want
endif;
```

Will `foo3(1) = '1'` be true or false?

Comment: Here the numerical value of the default value for `foo3` is 100 decimal and the if statement condition will be TRUE without an intervening assignment following declaration. The leftmost element is most significant. Functions providing arithmetic operator overloads use aliases with subtype indication in descending order derived from operand length to specify the rightmost element as (0) internally. A returned result would be in descending order whereupon an assignment associates leftmost to leftmost and requires matching elements, providing an implicit subtype conversion.

Comment: You could demonstrate the answers to your questions yourself by simulation. Package numeric_std for instance can convert a signed value to integer, e.g. `report "foo3 = " & integer'image(to_integer(foo3));` which would work for all signed values that fit within the minimum range of type INTEGER. You could likewise assign elements and examine the resulting value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For consistency across VHDL's math packages, it is better to use downto.

```
variable foo1 : signed (7 downto 0);
```

This has nothing to do with numeric_std package.   As with the numeric_std package, the leftmost element is always the most significant element, independent of whether you use downto or to.  Also interesting with numeric_std, the value is in no way dependent on the indices - so (15 downto 8) works the same as (7 downto 0).

On the other hand, with VHDL-2008's fixed point and floating point packages, the only direction supported is downto.   The actual range has meaning.  With fixed point, the indices have weight.   Negative indices are the fractional part.

```
variable foo4 : sfixed(7 downto -2) ; -- 8 bits of integer, 2 bits of fraction
variable foo5 : sfixed(7 downto 1) ; -- even numbers only.
```

For more on fixed and floating point, see:
https://synthworks.com/papers/vhdl_fixedfloat_lewis_bishop_date_2007.pdf

For more on unsigned / signed, see:
https://synthworks.com/papers/vhdl_math_tricks_mapld_2003.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In IEEE Standard VHDL Synthesis Packages:

> The  type UNSIGNED represents an unsigned binary integer with the most
> significant bit on the left, while the type SIGNED represents a
> two’s-complement binary integer with **the most significant bit on the
> left**. In particular, a one-element SIGNED vector represents the
> integer values –1 and 0.

So the number will be interpreted as 100, regardless the range direction. However, accessing or assigning a single element will match with the `to` range, i.e. `foo3(1) = '1'`.

Comment: The quote is from IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values, 16.8.5.1 General. 8.4 Indexed names "An indexed name denotes an element of an array." "The expressions specify the index values for the element; there shall be one such expression for each index position of the array, and each expression shall be of the type of the corresponding index. For the evaluation of an indexed name, the prefix and the expressions are evaluated. It is an error if an index value does not belong to the range of the corresponding index range of the array."